# Creating a Multi-Variable equation to create a "Most Favorable Supplier Index"

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I wanted to create a 'most favorable supplier index', where I want to assign a value to each supplier, ranging from 1-5 or 1-10, whichever, from the most and to the least preferred suppliers. There are couple of different metrics, that need to be taken into consideration to come at this value, which includes, current supplier business per day, since when has the business been serving its customers, supplier customer reviews, supplier cost per product etc.

Wanted to know how I can create an equation to incorporate all these and other factors to generate the "score" for each supplier, also as given that all these will have separate and unique units, how can I incorporate that?

Would be great if I could just get a direction on how to go about it.

Thanks.. :)

Comment: This sounds like a business question, not a math question.